# Does GNU awk accept intervals specified using braces in regular expressions?

Tags: awk, regex

Which types of regular expressions are recognized by awk? This command

```
echo "aa" | gawk '/a{2,3}/ {print}'
```

does not return anything, whilst

```
echo "a{2,3}" | gawk '/a{2,3}/ {print}'
```

returns `a{2,3}`.

Since other extended regex features like alternation are instead recognized, where can I find a precise reference? From the [GNU `find` manual's section on awk regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dawk-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002dawk-regular-expression-syntax), the above syntax should be accepted, since:

> Intervals are specified by ‘{’ and ‘}’.

Comment: First one returns "aa" perfectly fine to me.

Comment: You sure you have gawk installed ? Ubuntu (prior to 15.10 i think ) by default comes with mawk

Comment: I have been trying to do the same thing with awk i.e.  echo "aa" | awk '/a{2,3}/ {print}' which returns nothing. Why is awk ignoring intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators):

> Initially, because old programs may use ‘{’ and ‘}’ in regexp
>   constants, gawk did not match interval expressions in regexps.
>
> However, beginning with version 4.0, gawk does match interval
>   expressions by default. This is because compatibility with POSIX has
>   become more important to most gawk users than compatibility with old
>   programs.

Since [Ubuntu 12.04 has GNU awk 3.1.8 and 14.04 has 4.0.1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gawk), you must be on 12.04 (or another such old release).

---

Set `POSIXLY_CORRECT` for POSIX behaviour:

```
$ echo "a{2,3}" | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gawk '/a{2,3}/ {print}'
$ echo "aa" | POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 gawk '/a{2,3}/ {print}'
aa
```

Or, use the `-r` option if you want to keep GNU extensions and use interval expressions:

> `-r`
>   `--re-interval`
>
> Allow interval expressions (see [Regexp Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators)) in regexps. This is
>   now gawk’s default behavior. Nevertheless, this option remains (both
>   for backward compatibility and for use in combination with
>   `--traditional`).

Comment: My bad, this was even written in the manual...

Comment: A related question: the gawk manual claims to have extended regex as those in egrep (with the options written in your answer), but backreferences are not allowed inside regex (it is allowed only in replacement strings). This seems not in agreement with https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/gnu_002dawk-regular-expression-syntax.html#gnu_002dawk-regular-expression-syntax

Comment: @VeryHardCoder not very surprising. My guess is that find probably implements gawk's features on top of other regex engines it already supports, so back references come free with the rest.